# Difference between forward-mode and reverse-mode automatic differentiation?

Tags: optimization, backpropagation, derivative, gradient, automatic-differentiation

I have difficulty grasping the difference between forward and reverse mode automatic differentiation. To understand this problem I have created a simple equation and broken this equation into small chunks and find partial derivatives of it.

$$z = (x+y)(x-y)$$
$$a = x+y$$
$$b = x-y$$
$$z = a*b$$

for simplicity we are only going to find derivative of $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}$.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial b} \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}=b+a$$

where

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial a} =  \frac{\partial (ab)}{\partial a} = b$$

$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (x+y)}{\partial x} = 1
$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial b} =  \frac{\partial (ab)}{\partial b} = a$$
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (x-y)}{\partial x} = 1$$

Consider $x=2$ and $y=1$ if we propagate these values

$$x = 2$$
$$y = 1$$

$$a = x+y = 3$$
$$b = x-y = 1$$

$$z = a*b = 3$$

In the above case how do we do forward-mode and reverse-mode automatic differentiation?

Comment: This question might e a better fot on math SE, or maybe even better at https://or.stackexchange.com/.  If you want we might migrate it for you.

Comment: I asked this question here because these modes are used in pytorch and tensorflow for deep learning applications. I thought of posting it in math SE but this question might be too specific for that SE. "or" SE I heard it for the first time but I believe its more catered toward management related topics; I might be wrong !

Comment: OK, so lets see if you get an answer here.